# SQL joining other table with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `classes` 
JOIN `classes_students` 
ON `classes`.`id` = `classes_students`.`class`
```

And I need to add condition for selecting just classes, in which are not currently logged student (user ID is not in classes_students connected with class id) and also count how many students are in that class.

Table structure:
    classes: id, name, etc
    classes_students: class_id, user_id, etc

Table data:

```
classes: 
1 | test 
2 | test2
3 | test3

classes_students:
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 4
3 | 5
```

Expected output if im user with id 1:
classes names (with number of students in):

```
2 (1 student)
3 (2 students)
```

All this in one query. It is possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Probably. Setup a SQLFiddle with some data and we can help you figure it out. Without know the table structure and seeing an example of the output you want we would only be guessing.

Comment: Why one query? Show us some sample table data and the result you want from that query.

Comment: Sample data added, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select classid, count(*)
from class
  left join student on student.classid = class.classid
group by classid
```

Glad help for you

Comment: This shows me classes, where I'm in. But I want to show other classes (where im not in).

Comment: You should add where class.classid not in (1,2,3,..) before group by

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$user_id = 1; // current user_id

$query = "SELECT `classes`.`id`, `classes`.`name`, COUNT(*) as students FROM `classes` 
          JOIN `classes_students` 
          ON `classes`.`id` = `classes_students`.`class_id`
          AND `classes_students`.`user_id` != $user_id 
          GROUP BY `classes_students`.`class_id`
          ";
```

Comment: Yes, its workin, but when in that my class is other student, that class will show up too. And that's not what I expect.

Comment: @JeleanThomas, not really understand this "but when in that my class is other student, that class will show up too". I thought you wanted to extract classes that don't relate to the current logged user. The above query should get all classes which don't have relation with current user

Comment: yes I want. BUT when there is another record in classes_students for selected class with another than actually logged in user, it will show up. U can try it on ur own. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! :) 
Thank you guys for ur help.

```
$user_id = 1; // current user_id

$query = "SELECT `classes`.`id`, `classes`.`name`, COUNT(*) as students FROM `classes` 
          LEFT JOIN `classes_students` 
          ON `classes`.`id` = `classes_students`.`class_id`
          WHERE `classes`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `class_id` FROM `classes_students` WHERE `user_id`='.$user_id.')
          GROUP BY `classes_students`.`class_id`
          ";
```